# Animation nodes, join a list / group of objects into a single mesh

Tags: animation-nodes

just struggling with this one, the solution in the picture does what I need but builds up rather than refreshing each frame. This problem stems from my general lack of programming nous.

I essentially want a set of instances that I'm generating elsewhere to be one mesh so that I can easily perform other operations / modifiers on them as a whole,

cheers

Chris

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a loop, you need to know, that loop inputs list of something, and break apart this list into elements inside loop. Output makes reverse things - all elements join into one list, so you don't need to do this dirty joining work.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how this can be done with Collections since groups are removed from 2.80?

Comment: @yaruncan did you try Objects from collection?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this hunting, here are nodes for 2.91.
Also if you are new (like me) and can't 'find' the generators, you have to hit the + button to make a New Generator Output and select Mesh.

Overall, this makes tubes and balls from a mesh edge input.

[image]